# Ruby on Rails: Как правильно создать модели и миграции?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Нужно создать две модели с помощью генератора. Выглядят они [так](http://68.media.tumblr.com/c580d5c5b4c61053c732ca23a3da00f8/tumblr_inline_nqrp62ydc21ttxe4g_1280.png)
После выполнения миграции и перехода в rails console мы должны успешно выполнить  [следующие команды](http://68.media.tumblr.com/11b50ac0928935274751e2293ef38a6f/tumblr_inline_nqrp7bazHk1ttxe4g_1280.png):

```
project = Project.create title: "Мой проект"
todo = Todo.create text: "Обсудить проект с женой"
project.todos << todo
```

Проблема: На второй команде получаю RollBack и дальше ничего не получается

Код классов:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :todos
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :project
end
```

Код миграций:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
  create_table :projects do |t|
   t.string :title

   t.timestamps
   end 
  end 
  end

class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
create_table :todos do |t|
  t.string :text
  t.boolean :isCompleted
  t.references :project, foreign_key: true
  t.timestamps
  end
end
end
```

Какими командами можно сгенерировать модели, чтобы всё заработало? Помогите найти ошибки, спасибо!

Comment: А какое исключение выдаёт?

Comment: И ещё если вы будете следовать соглашению о именованию символов в рельсах, то избежите многих подводных камней.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ дело говорит, Rails сильно опирается на конвенции именования и в некоторых местах сам преобразует между ними, в результате могут возникать разнообразные сюрпризы. Откатите миграцию `CreateTodos` (если она у вас применена) и замените `isCompleted` на `is_completed`.

Answer (score 2):

```
todo = Todo.create text: "Обсудить проект с женой"
```

Ага. Конечно. **Вы этой строчкой создаёте `Todo`, не принадлежащий `Project`'у.**

А это противоречит:

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :project # <-- этой строчке
end
```

...т. к. с Rails 5 ассоциации `belongs_to` **обязательны к заполнению**, это валидируется автоматически, и если вам не нужно, требует явного отключения таким манером (но не делайте так, сейчас объясню, почему):

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, optional: true
end
```

Но в вашем случае не надо, т. к. ваша модель данных сейчас не предполагает существования задач без проектов. Вам просто нужно не сохранять задачу до тех пор, пока в ней не появится `project_id`. `create` сохраняет её немедленно.

Можно задать `project_id` явно:

```
todo = Todo.create(text: "Починить ассоциации", project_id: project.id)
```

...но это строит предположение о том, как называется внешний ключ. Этому, по-хорошему, место в модели, но поскольку вы следуете конвенциям Rails в этом вопросе, это нет смысла писать в модели прямым текстом: Rails уже знает. Так что можно сделать просто:

```
project.todos.create(text: "Починить ассоциации")
```

---

**Бонус:** Я б даже научил базу самостоятельно за этим следить и отказываться записывать такие вещи, даже если валидации по какой-то причине выполнены не будут. Дополнительная мера безопасности. Это очень легко, надо чуть поменять определение одной из колонок `todos`, сделав наличие значения в `project_id` обязательным:

```
t.references :project, foreign_key: true, null: false
#                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ NOT NULL в SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Ту уже написал модели вручную, зачем тебе их генерировать там у тебя все верно. С рейлсом пятым я не знаком но ты вроде хочешь написать связь и сохранить в базе. Запись связи в базу делают примерно так:

project = Project.new(name: "vjvjjjhjhjhbjh")

todo = project.todos.create(text: "jvkvkghvjhbkjhlvg")